# Multiple Yii EJuiAutoCompleteFkField widgets on a single page: How to assign unique DOM ids to each?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, yii

I'm trying to use multiple EJuiAutoCompleteFkField widgets in a single view (actually some ajax loaded divs within a view). Anyone know of a way to give the juiautocomplete widgets a uinque DOM ID so they can all function separately?

Currently only the first one works cause it's not unique.

I was hoping for something like 'htmloptions' below to set the id, like you find in other Yii widgets

```
<?php 
 $this->widget('EJuiAutoCompleteFkField', array(
  'model'=>$smpNull, 
  'attribute'=>'cancer_id', //the FK field (from CJuiInputWidget)
  'sourceUrl'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('/samples/cancerAutoComplete'), 
  'showFKField'=>false,
  'FKFieldSize'=>10, 
  'relName'=>'cancer', // the relation name defined above
  'displayAttr'=>'CancerName',  // attribute or pseudo-attribute to display
  'autoCompleteLength'=>50,
  'options'=>array(
    'minLength'=>3,
   ),
  'htmlOptions'=>array(
   'id'=>'Events_cancer_id',
  ),
 ));
?>
```

Thanks !

Comment: not used EJuiAutoCompleteFkField before, but on the off chance have you tried adding the id to the 'options' param?

Comment: actually, looking at the source code quickly (very quickly, so sorry if you've already tried this!), it looks like it does use htmlOptions, if you look at lines 197 and 199 of v1.5 it's setting htmlOptions, so you could just add another custom param and configure the `init()` method to cater for those options?

Comment: Stu, I did try it in the options param, but will have a look at the code where you suggest.  Figured I'd ask around first. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I modified the extension to enable multiple fields per page:

The new EJuiAutoCompleteFkField.php

```
<?php
/* 
 * EJuiAutoCompleteFkField class file
 *
 * @author Jeremy Dunn <jeremy.j.dunn@gmail.com>
 * @link http://www.yiiframework.com/
 * @version 1.5
 */

Yii::import('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete');
class EJuiAutoCompleteFkField extends CJuiAutoComplete {

    /**
     * @var boolean whether to show the FK field.
     */
    public $showFKField = false;

    /**
     * @var integer length of the FK field if visible
     */
    public $FKFieldSize = 10;
    /**
     * @var string the relation name to the FK table
     */
    public $relName;
    /**
     * @var string the relation name to the FK table
     */
    public $idSuffix;
    /**
     * @var string extension to append to id fields for uniqneness
     */
    public $displayAttr;

    /**
     * @var integer width of the AutoComplete field
     */
    public $autoCompleteLength = 50;

    /**
     * @var string the ID of the FK field
     */
    private $_fieldID;

    /**
     * @var string the ID of the hidden field to save the display value
     */
    private $_saveID;

    /**
     * @var string the ID of the AutoComplete field
     */
    private $_lookupID;

    /**
     * @var string the ID for the hidden field
     */
    private $_hiddenID;

    /**
     * @var string the initial display value
     */
    private $_display;
    /**
     * @var string name of the lookup field
     */
    private $_name;

    public function init() {
        parent::init(); // ensure necessary assets are loaded

        // JJD 8/3/11 make EJuiAutoCompleteFkField work for child rows where attribute like [$i]FieldName
        // get the ID which will be created for the actual field when it is rendered.
        // don't let resolveNameID() change $this->attribute which is needed to generate the actual field
        $attr = $this->attribute;
        $tempHtmlOpts = array();
        CHtml::resolveNameID($this->model, $attr, $tempHtmlOpts);
        $id = $tempHtmlOpts['id'].'_'.$this->idSuffix;
        $this->_fieldID = $id;
        $this->_saveID = $id . '_save';
        $this->_lookupID = $id .'_lookup';
        $this->_hiddenID = $id .'_hidden';
        $this->_name = $tempHtmlOpts['id'].'_lookup';

        $related = $this->model->{$this->relName}; // get the related record
        $value = CHtml::resolveValue($this->model, $this->attribute);
        $this->_display=(!empty($value) ? $related->{$this->displayAttr} : '');

        if (!isset($this->options['minLength']))
            $this->options['minLength'] = 2;

        if (!isset($this->options['maxHeight']))
            $this->options['maxHeight']='100';

        $this->htmlOptions['size'] = $this->autoCompleteLength;
        // fix problem with Chrome 10 validating maxLength for the auto-complete field
        $this->htmlOptions['maxlength'] = $this->autoCompleteLength;

        // setup javascript to do the work
        $this->options['create']="js:function(event, ui){\$(this).val('".addslashes($this->_display)."');}";  // show initial display value
        // after user picks from list, save the ID in model/attr field, and Value in _save field for redisplay
        $this->options['select']="js:function(event, ui){\$('#".$this->_fieldID."').val(ui.item.id);\$('#".$this->_saveID."').val(ui.item.value);}";
        // when the autoComplete field loses focus, refresh the field with current value of _save
        // this is either the previous value if user didn't pick anything; or the new value if they did
        // $this->htmlOptions['onblur']="$(this).val($('#".$this->_saveID."').val());";
    }

    public function run() {
        // first render the FK field.  This is the actual data field, populated by autocomplete.select()
        if ($this->showFKField) {
            echo CHtml::activeTextField($this->model, $this->attribute, array('size'=>$this->FKFieldSize, 'readonly'=>'readonly'));
        } else {
            echo CHtml::activeHiddenField($this->model,$this->attribute, array('id'=>$this->_hiddenID));
        }

        // second, the hidden field used to refresh the display value
        echo CHtml::hiddenField($this->_saveID,$this->_display, array('id'=>$this->_saveID)); 

        // third, the autoComplete field itself
        $this->htmlOptions['id'] = $this->_lookupID;
        $this->htmlOptions['name'] = $this->_name;       
        parent::run();

        // fouth, an image button to empty all three fields
        /*
        $label=Yii::t('DR','Remove '). ucfirst($this->relName); // TODO: how to translate relname?
        $deleteImageURL = '/images/text_field_remove.png'; 
        echo CHtml::image($deleteImageURL, $label,
            array('title'=>$label,
                'name' => 'remove'.$this->_fieldID,
                'style'=>'margin-left:6px;',
                // JJD 4/27/12 #1350 trigger onchange event for display field, in case there's an event attached (e.g. unsaved-changes-warning)
                'onclick'=>"$('#".$this->_fieldID."').val('').trigger('change');$('#".$this->_saveID."').val('');$('#".$this->_lookupID."').val('');",
            )
        );
         * 
         */
    }
}
?>
```

and the usage in the view:

```
<?php 
$this->widget('EJuiAutoCompleteFkField', array(
'model'=>$smpCancerDefault, 
'attribute'=>'cancer_id', //the FK field (from CJuiInputWidget)
'sourceUrl'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('/samples/cancerAutoComplete'), 
'showFKField'=>false,
'FKFieldSize'=>10, 
'relName'=>'cancer', // the relation name defined above
'displayAttr'=>'CancerName',  // attribute or pseudo-attribute to display
'autoCompleteLength'=>50,
'idSuffix'=>"myUniqueSuffix", // added this var to allow for unique field ids
'options'=>array(
'minLength'=>3,
 ),
));
?>
```

Comment: When using the latest available extension "EJuiAutoCompleteFkField" I can use the widget with no problems, but when I implement this solution to use multiple widgets on single page I can't retrieve the FK Key. Any ideas? I'm using the exact same code posted here.

Comment: @WebDevPT it could be a version issue. I'm using 1.5